# How removing rare words affects model performance?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

Let's say you want to build a model for text prediction and your dataset contains 5M words.The unique words(the vocab size is 59k). But if i remove all words that appear less than 4 times in the whole dataset the number of unique words drops down to 20k. What I want to know is does removing these rare words affect my model performance in any way?

Comment: This is not a programming question, you should ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. If you're using a traditional 'bag of words' representation, yes you should remove rare words and it will very likely improve performance because not doing it will cause massive overfitting ([example](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/110964/is-my-model-classification-overfitting/110965#110965)). the problem might be different with embeddings, it depends.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will affect model performance, how much and in what direction depends on many factors such as: what sort of model you are using to do prediction, what the end application is, if you are using [distributional approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributional_semantics) to word meaning (i.e. word embedding) and what approach exactly *et cetera*. It is often difficult to learn [word embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) for rare words as most embedding methods require many observations of a word to learn a good representation. There are exceptions to this, for example, Schick & Schütze's Attentive Mimicking approach [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.01617.pdf) which has had some success. So, if you only see some words less than 4 times in your large dataset, chances are your word embedding is not going to learn a *meaningful representation* for those particular words, and therefore, the removal or inclusion is not going to have a consistent impact performance. Learning a "meaningful representation" is in part related to stability. According to the work by Wendlandt et al. [[2]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09692.pdf), lower frequency words tend to have lower stability---defined as the percent overlap between nearest neighbours in an embedding space, that is, the overlap as measured by the cosine similarity between two lists of the top 10 nearest neighbours of a word *W* in two embedding spaces *A* and *B*. To put this in simple terms, if a word *W* has low stability, the top 10 words "most similar" to *W* changes more significantly between embeddings (see Table 1 in  [[2]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09692.pdf) for an example). Hence, my assumption that inclusion or exclusion or these words is likely not going to have a consistent impact on performance. The best way to check is to implement your solution with and without those low frequency words and see how performance varies.

[[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.01617.pdf) Schick, T. and Schütze, H., 2019. Attentive mimicking: Better word embeddings by attending to informative contexts. *arXiv preprint arXiv:1904.01617*.

[[2]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09692.pdf) Wendlandt, L., Kummerfeld, J.K. and Mihalcea, R., 2018. Factors influencing the surprising instability of word embeddings. *arXiv preprint arXiv:1804.09692*.

Comment: thank you very much. so now i'm running some tests to see how performance will change after removing these words

Comment: Just to say that it's a very careful answer. I saw somebody gave you a -1, it's probably because we're not supposed to answer non-programming questions on SO. Don't hesitate to join us as a contributor on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: @mucho You're welcome, best of luck with it

Comment: @Erwan thank you, I'll have to come check it out :)

Comment: I hope I won't get a minus for this
  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/115257/how-to-create-better-sequences-for-word-prediction-models-the-following-is-my-c